# Regular Expression for Google Analytics to determine page

Tags: regex

I'm looking specifically for a regular expression that will grab the last term of a URL. This is not always a file name, it may not end in .html or .php, so I'll need to make sure that the regular expression is grabbing the **last** term from the URL.

---

Example:

I need to grab www.mydomain.com/anything_can_be_here/**thankyoupage**

I need to extract "thankyoupage" even when there can be any term preceding it in the URL.

Also note, there is no file extension on the thankyoupage URL segment.

Comment: Do you need everything after the domain name? or just the very last part (that is excluding path/folders)?

Comment: Just the very last part -- anything after the final slash. example: www.mydomain.com/this  or www.mydomain.com/other/other/this

Comment: So you want the last component of the URL's path? What happens if you have `http://example.com/where?is=pancakes/house`? Is there any good reason that you need a single regex for this?

Comment: @mu yeah, google analytics requires a regex to pull the page viewed. I need to gather the last segment of the URL.

Comment: When you edit you question multiple times. nothing makes sense anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[^\/]+)\/.*?\/([^\/]+)(?:\?.*)?$/
```

For example, the result of this:

```
m = 'http://example.com/where/is?the=pancakes/house'.match(/^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[^\/]+)\/.*?\/([^\/]+)(?:\?.*)?$/);
```

is this array:

```
["http://example.com/where/is?the=pancakes/house", "is"]
```

And this:

```
m = 'http://example.com/where/is'.match(/^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[^\/]+)\/.*?\/([^\/]+)(?:\?.*)?$/)
```

Results in:

```
["http://example.com/where/is", "is"]
```

And this:

```
m = 'http://example.com/'.match(/^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[^\/]+)\/.*?\/([^\/]+)(?:\?.*)?$/)
```

Results in `null`.

And your component is in `m[1]` and that comes from `([^\/]+)`. The `(?:[^\/]+)` will take care of the hostname (and the userinfo if it happens to be present), the `(?:\?.*)?$` part will take care of any trailing CGI arguments.

Depending on your URLs, you could replace `^(?:http:\/\/)?` with `^http:\/\/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only feeding it urls, something simple as `.*/(.*)` should work

that's assuming there is a '/' after the .com/.org/whatever

otherwise you'll get everything after the http://

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the path name, which can be access using:

```
window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Sorry I think i had stated that I only need a regular expression, no supported language options other than a regex.

Comment: Your question is tagged with `javascript`, so in case u are using javascript, no regex is needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^http:\/\/.*/(.+)$
```

It will look for string starting with `http://` then will go all the way till the last `/` and store everything after the last `/` into `$1` variable.

Comment: You're missing a backslash. And what happens with `http://example.com/where?is=pancakes/house`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want

```
console.log(window.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0]);
```

Comment: Nope -- need a regular expression

Comment: So why this post is tagged by "javascript"? Try this regexp '/\/([^/]*)$/i'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "www.mydomain.com/other/other/this";  
var path = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?.*\/([^\/]+)/.exec(str)[1]; //this
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp:

```
/(\/([^\/]+))+/g
```

Take the 3rd element of the resulting array:

```js
var a='http://www.host.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/dd.pp';
var regexp=/(\/([^\/]+))+/g;
var result=regexp.exec(a)
if( result.length==3) {
    document.write('<p>'+result[2]+'</p>');
} else {
    document.write('<p>Fail</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it outmyself, thanks anyways guys

```
/\/*\/thanks/
```

will match /thanks